# Call 'structure' to save in postgres using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a 'publication' data structure, and my table name in postgres is 'publications'. I get a tweet from streaming and parse it according in class TweetFetcher. How do I call publication controller to save it to the database? PublicationController has the standard scrum abilities (new, create, show, edit...), where create is:

```
def create
  @publication = Publications.new(params[:publication])
  if @publication.save
        redirect_to :action => 'list'
  else
        @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
        render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

and parte of my twitter code is

```
class TweetFetcher
    def saveTweet(parsedTweet)

        pT = JSON.parse(parsedTweet)

        #save here. like this?
        #PublicationController.create(parsedTweet)

    end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using your controller in this situation, instead you can just build your record like this:

```
class TweetFetcher
    def saveTweet(parsedTweet)

        pT = JSON.parse(parsedTweet)

        publication = Publications.new
        publication.sample_field = pT.sample_field
        ... # set additional attributes
        publication.save

    end

end
```

Additionally, here is some advice/information that is not directly related to your question, but are things you should know:

1. The class name of your models should be singular, so instead of `Publications`, it should be `Publication`.
2. Method and variable names should be in snake case rather than camel case (i.e. `save_tweet` instead of `saveTweet` or `parsed_tweet` instead of `parsedTweet`).
3. The new hash syntax is prefered, unless of course you are using a Ruby version below 1.9. This looks like `{ key: value }` instead of `{ key => value }`.
4. Indentation for Ruby code is typically 2 spaces.

That being said, I would change your code like this:

**PublicationsController#create**

```
def create
  @publication = Publication.new(params[:publication])

  if @publication.save
    redirect_to action: 'list'
  else
    @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
    render action: 'new'
  end
end
```

**TweeFetcher**

```
class TweetFetcher
  def save_tweet(tweet)
    parsed_tweet = JSON.parse(tweet)

    publication = Publication.new
    publication.sample_field = parsed_tweet.sample_field
    ... # set additional attributes
    publication.save
  end
end
```